# How can I generate the density information of vehicles in only SUMO?

Tags: sumo, vehicle-routing

This is my sumocfg file code in the SUMO program.

```
<input>
    <net-file value="updated.net.xml"/>
    <route-files value="trips.trips.xml"/>
</input>

<time>
    <begin value="0"/>
</time>

<report>
    <verbose value="true"/>
    <no-step-log value="true"/>
</report>
```

updated.net.xml is network file which I write, and trips.trips.xml is just the vehicle mobility file.

In https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Output/Lane-_or_Edge-based_Traffic_Measures, there is the density information format, but I don't know how can I generate the additional output file including vehicle density information.

What code should I add here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is stated under 'Instantiating within the Simulation', you need to add an additional file under  as follows:

```
<input>
    <net-file value = 'xxx'/>
    <route-files value = 'xxx'/>
    <additional-files value = 'xxx'/>
</input>
```

In the additional file, add the required edge and lane ids that are to be measured.